How to catch an error on type ReadableStreamDefaultController in Javascript
I'm learning about streams and have been understanding it so far. Until recently when I had to face error handling in a custom readable stream, the code is below:
export default defineEventHandler(event => {
    // ... Some code for validation

    return new ReadableStream({
        start: async (controller) => {
          await scraper(controller, body.url);
          controller.close();
        }
    })
}

async function scraper(controller: ReadableStreamDefaultController) {
   // ... Steps before error
   if (valueDoesntMatch) controller.error({message: 'Error message', name: 'ERR_MESSAGE_TYPE'})
}


This code lives inside a server route /api/proxy. The server is Nitro (since I'm using Nuxt). Whenever an error is thrown from controller I get the following:
 ERROR  [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Website couldn't be reached
  at createError (./node_modules/.pnpm/h3@1.12.0/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:78:15)  
  at Server.toNodeHandle (./node_modules/.pnpm/h3@1.12.0/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:2268:21)  
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

So my question is how would I catch this error or how can I handle it?
